# Update column with value of another column or another column

Tags: postgresql, update

With PostgreSQL (I'm using the version 9.1) is it possible to do mass update with a single query a column value with the value of another column, but if the other column value is null, to use the value of a third column, and if the third one is absent to use the current datetime (all the column have type `timestamp`)

I need to change

```
columnA columnB columnC
null    foo     bar
null    null    baz
null    null    null
```

to

```
columnA columnB columnC
foo     foo     bar
baz     null    baz
quz     null    null
```

where `quz` is the current datetime.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html) to do the update:

```
UPDATE ...
SET columnA = COALESCE(columnB, columnC, now());
```

`COALESCE` will return the first non-null value in the list that you provide.

Answer (score 13):

One can use [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to provide defaults instead of possibly NULL values.  It is a variadic function, so it can take any number of parameters.  The return value will be the first non-NULL parameter (if there is none, it still returns NULL).

Using it, you `UPDATE` might look like:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET columnA = COALESCE(columnB, columnC, 'quz');
```